# How to add spaces between tuples in a string

Tags: python

I'm trying to solve a question on hackerrank (question is entitled: Compress the string!). I have managed to solve most of the it, but I'm not able to add between the tuples:
string with tuples:

```py
'(1, 1)(3, 2)(1, 3)(2, 1)'
```

But I want to add a single space in between the tuples.

This is my solution to the question:

```py
import itertools
def CompressTheString(S):
    Sout = ''
    for key, group in itertools.groupby(S, None):
        N = len(tuple(group))
        Sout += ''.join(str((N, int(key))))
    print(Sout)
CompressTheString('12223311')
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  Basic string manipulation is included in any tutorial on the topic; Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing educational resources.

Comment: I'm still trying to do some research, maybe let me add my solution to the question.

Comment: I have tried to add the space after a specific number of characters, in this case 6 and it works. But I'm thinking what of in a case where the length of characters is not specific, for example in '(1, 10)(3, 2)(110, 3)(2, 1)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has two main problems:

1. Conceptually, you're converting your data to string too early. Keep it as data until you need to print it.
2. Appending to a string in a loop is generally not ideal. Instead, append to a list then join it, converting the elements to strings if needed. Although in this case, you can use  `print()` to convert the tuples to strings and join them for you.

```
def CompressTheString(S):
    out = []
    for key, group in itertools.groupby(S, None):
        N = len(tuple(group))
        out.append((N, int(key)))
    print(*out)
```

For what it's worth, I would take `print` out of the function and turn it into a beautiful [generator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator), as well as some other changes:

```
def compress(string):
    for key, group in itertools.groupby(string):
        yield len(tuple(group)), int(key)

print(*compress('12223311'))
```

By the way, `''.join(str())` is redundant. Remove `''.join()`.

Comment: Thank you as well it works, "Sout" is undefined in your code but I understand it. I'm just a beginner so bear with me, I haven't yet learnt "generator" (I will cover it) and I also did know about how to use print that way, again thank you :)

Comment: @Thomas Whoops, that was a typo. Fixed now. Welcome! :) Yeah I figured you were a beginner so I focused on fixing your solution rather than recommending a more advanced way.

Comment: Is there a python curriculum I need to be aware about or something, like a learning path?

Comment: @Thomas try the official [Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html)?

Answer (score -1):

you can change your code, but i will suggest you to review it

```
import itertools
def CompressTheString(S):
    counts = []
    Sout = ''
    for key, group in itertools.groupby(S, None):
        N = len(tuple(group))
        counts.append(''.join(str((N, int(key)))))
    Sout = ' '.join(counts)
    print(Sout)
CompressTheString('12223311')
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! I was thinking of adding the space every after a specific number of characters, in this case 6. But the I thought, what if the number of characters is not specific. For example: '(1, 1)(30, 2)(1, 3)(211, 1)'

Comment: What's the point of doing `Sout = ' '.join(counts)` every loop, when you could do it once at the end instead? What's more, you don't need to explicitly join when you could have `print` do it for you: `print(*counts)`

Comment: As well, `''.join(str())` is redundant. Remove `''.join()`. I mentioned this in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63385302/4518341) too.